# Cannot print indices from array

Tags: java

After I compile my code, I see this as the output:

[I@7852e922

I'm assuming I need to use Array.toString after some searching but when I  I seem to have other errors so I'm assuming I'm not putting it in the right place.

Here is my code:

```
public class TwoSum 
    {
        static int[] arraynums = new int[]{2, 7, 11, 15};
        static int target = 9;

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            //TwoSum name = new TwoSum();
            //name.twoSums(arraynums, target);
            System.out.println(twoSums(arraynums, target));
        }
            public static int[] twoSums(int[] nums, int target) 
            {
                int sum = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++)
                    {   
                        sum = nums[i] + nums[j];
                        if (sum == target)
                        {
                            //System.out.println(i + " " + j);
                            return new int[] {i,j};
                        }

                    }
                }
                return new int[] {};
            }
    }
```

Comment: try `System.out.println(Arrays.tostring (twoSums(arraynums, target)));`

Comment: it is because you just printed the array. What output you want to be printed? the value inside the array?

Comment: i don´t get the question? you just answered your own question by providing the necesserray function to print the array.